# Workflow 4.0 Activities not found

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 Beta2.

I am creating a new workflow project. But under New_Project_WorkFlow the sequential activity workflow was not listed for .net framework 4.

And even if I choose workflow console application I don't have an option to add a sequential activity in add -new item by right clicking on the project

Toolbox looks different too compare to VS2008.EventDriven.AddExternalevent activities are not seen.(But these are available if I choose .net framework 3.5)

I need to create a sequential activity which consume a web service using the clientOperation activity.But client operation activity also not available in toolbox.same for Console.readline.

But the examples given in web mention all these. I am quite confused by VS2010 IDE. Why I can't find any of these activity in My Vs2010 toolbox? I posted a similar question earlier. But I think the qustion was not explaining all this problems.

http://www.biztalkgurus.com/media/p/21915.aspx

This is the webcast I am referring for above mentioned workflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are different designer experiences, and totally different framework classes depending on whether you select Framework 3.5 or 4.0

In order to create a sequential workflow in WF 4.0, use the Sequence activity (in the Control Flow) toolbox group, by dragging that into a new Activity.

In order to consume a WCF web service within your sequence, the easiest way may be using add service reference (right-click project, add service reference, build).

Answer (score 0):

Sequential activity located in the Toolbox in Control Flow group

Answer (score 0):

In wf4 you don't create workflows projects.
You create other projects to contain the workflow.

For example Class library or Console Applications.

To create a Sequence workflow:

right click the project and select:    Add | New Item | Workflow | Activity.

All workflows in wf4 are called Activity.

Once you have that Activity file (it has an .xaml extension), you open it.
The design surface is displayed.

Now you can add a Sequence from the Toolbox (View | Toolbox) to the design surface.